# Change div innerHTML through IHTMLDocument2 and C++

Tags: c++, ihtmldocument2, ihtmldocument

I'm trying to change the content of a div using IHTMLDocument2 interface this way:

```
    IHTMLElementCollection* collection = NULL;
    IDispatch* mydiv;

    doc2->get_all(&collection);
    long count;
    collection->get_length(&count);     //just to check I get something

    CComVariant varstr = L"mydivname";
    CComVariant varint = 0;
    collection->item(varstr, varint, &mydiv);    //this works I get the div
    IHTMLElement* htmldiv;
    mydiv->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement, (void**)&htmldiv);

    CComBSTR html;
    htmldiv->get_innerHTML(&html);      //works too, I get the current content

    HRESULT hr=htmldiv->put_innerText(L"hello");      //this does not work but returns S_OK

    collection->Release();
```

So the content of my div is just cleared and not replaced with "hello", I don't understand why, can it be a security issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752299(v=vs.85).aspx), the string passed to `put_innerText` is of type `BSTR`.

So, I would suggest trying some code like this:

```
CComBSTR text(OLESTR("hello"));
hr = htmldiv->put_innerText(text);
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help. The "tricky" part here is that we don't get compile-time errors when we pass an ordinary wchar_t string instead of a BSTR string (which makes sense from the compiler's perspective, considering the typedef definition of a BSTR :)